# Chrome Extension: Content Script -> Dynamic Function

Tags: google-chrome-extension, request, dynamic-function

I would like to call a dynamic function on a Content Script (Chrome Extension). But the common way doesn't work:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function cs_listener(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    [request.action]();
}
```

request.action is blah. Where function blah() is a....and now it comes...a function!

Error thrown:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: object is not a function
```

Someone got over this? I really don't like to make a switch for every action I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
window[request.action]();
```

as

```
[request.action]();
```

creates an *array* containing `request.action`, and tries to call that, which results in the error. `window[request.action]();` gets the property named `request.action` from `window` and calls that.

You also might want to check if the property is defined first:

```
if(typeof window[request.action] == "function")
  window[request.action]();
```

Comment: Yeah, window[request.action](); works. Strange, i tried it before, but it didn't work. Say hello to the typo. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be just calling that function from a background page, without sending a request:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "dynamic_function_name()"});
```

Comment: This works also, but has a limitation. You may not send a response from the content script to  the background script.

Comment: @Johnny True, you can still send result by initializing a request though.